# Configuring proxy settings for Google Chrome on Linux

Tags: linux, google-chrome, proxy

How do I configure proxy settings for Chrome on Linux? It doesn't have a configuration interface like Firefox. I'd like to configure it in a way that I don't have to type every time, the login and password.

EDIT: I'm using Fluxbox as my window manager.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try the `--proxy-server` command line option, and/or `http_proxy` environment variable.

```
google-chrome-stable --proxy-server="http://example.com:8080"
```

Also, Chrome/Chromium makes use of xdg scripts, so you can try configuring the proxy server in GNOME/KDE, and set up xdg scripts to use settings of the desktop environment. That is how I solved MIME-type file associations at least.

Comment: Calling the google chrome executable with the --proxy-server parameter worked fine, thanks. When browsing it pops up an authentication screen for every tab from the last session, is there a way to 'remember' the login and password, or make it authenticate automatically? using the --proxy-server parameter like --proxy-server="username:password@proxy-ip:port" didn't work.

Comment: 'google-chrome --proxy-pac-url=file:///...' works perfectly. There's no need to use http_proxy this no_proxy that. If you've got a pac file for use with firefox it'll work fine here. If you need help writing a .pac file google is your friend... 

But you can still configure via the command line. Please see man google-chrome for more information on flags and environment variables.

Comment: Re the username and password auth in chrome using the --proxy-server parameter - this appears to be a bug in Chrome - please star the issue here: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=615947

Comment: How does one enable and disable the proxy connection within a running chrome instance?

Comment: Note for anyone trying this: you may have to close all instances of Chrome that are currently running first. Otherwise `--proxy-server` seems to have no effect. I wasted about an hour on this.

Answer (score 2):

run this as root `gedit /usr/share/applications/google-chrome.desktop` then add your proxy settings as you would like ie `--proxy-server="http://127.0.0.1:8080"` then save and run chrome .

Comment: Can you explain how this works?

Comment: that's editing the chrome's app settings, so as to pick them during start.

Comment: Instead of gedit, you can use whatever text editor you want, as 'vi' for example

Comment: Ofcourse @pocjoc

Answer (score 2):

On Ubuntu 16.04 LTS with Chrome v53 (64 bit),
I had to set the http_proxy / HTTP_PROXY env variables to "http://proxyserver:port" for **all users** for Chrome to be able to communicate.

Modify /etc/profile

```
export {http,ftp,https,rsync}_proxy="http://proxyserver:port"
export {HTTP,FTP,HTTPS,RSYNC}_PROXY=$http_proxy
```

Answer (score 1):

Chrome uses the Proxy settings for your DE. If you use KDE it will use this. If you use Gnome it will use theirs. If you don't use either, I think it will try to use Gnome's, but not 100% sure.

If you go the the Wrench -> Under the Hood , you should have a button under Network labeled Change proxy settings. When I click this, in my case, it loads KDE Proxy settings.

If you don't use either KDE or Gnome, you could try browsing gconf , Chrome uses it to store it's settings.

Comment: How should I proceed under Fluxbox? Do I have to set the proxy for the whole system?

Comment: Did going to the settings under the Wrench give you the option to Change Proxy Settings?

Comment: Nope, it shows a page giving explanations of possible ways to set up proxy configurations. Apparently i'd have to change the proxy settings  on the OS itself, i'd like to set it only for chrome.

Comment: Doing a bit more reading out of curiosity, chrome either uses the system proxy or through the command switch. But now way to remember the username / password

Answer (score 1):

If you use socks proxy instead of slower http proxy,
You can create a launcher in Linux command:

/usr/bin/chromium www.google.com --proxy-server="socks5://127.0.0.1:1080"

before that click a desktop launcher "launcher.desktop" :

[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Exec=sslocal -c /home/user/config.json
Name[en_US.UTF-8]=sslocal_start.desktop
StartupNotify=false