# what is way to set Proxy in Chrome in Linux

Tags: linux, unix

When i go for change proxy setting in chrome it appears as `about:linux-proxy-config`.Please also tell me how do I install Proxy switchy in it.

Answer (score 1):

looks like your question is repeating this one. [Configuring proxy settings for google chrome on linux](https://superuser.com/questions/83007/configuring-proxy-settings-for-google-chrome-on-linux)

just to sum up, there is a 2 ways,

or you can start chrome with " --proxy-server="username:password@proxy-ip:port" option.

or you can  define environment variable called HTTP_PROXY , FTP_PROXY

Comment: thought it is not working after adding https,http and ftp proxy using terminal

Answer (score 0):

By default chrome uses system settings for proxy.
You can change this using extensions like foxyproxy [ https://getfoxyproxy.org/downloads.html ]

Comment: it is not using system proxy. I just installed linux for addition info.