# How to force all Linux apps to use SOCKS proxy

Tags: linux, networking, proxy

Using Linux, I need a way to route all network traffic of interface enp2s0 through SOCKS4 192.168.1.2:1080 (or any SOCKS proxy for that matter)
– something like Proxifier in Windows. 
The proxy works fine when manually set in Chrome or Firefox.

OS:
Linux Mint 19.1

Things I tried:

- I set the proxy manually in network settings,
  but it's just like I didn't set it;
  Chrome still connects directly.  Here's a screenshot:
  [image]
- Proxychains is working great,
  but I have to manually launch each app individually from the terminal.

I don't know how to use redsocks or iptables (yet).

I hope there's a GUI like Proxifier for Linux,
but a terminal (CLI)-based solution is okay.

Comment: Have you also looked at Redsocks2 (https://github.com/semigodking/redsocks)? It seems to be actively maintained and the documentation is easier to follow than Redsocks. Have you looked into the answers of https://askubuntu.com/a/513956/385961 and https://superuser.com/a/1122572/168962, regarding gsettings under Gnome and general shell environment variables to influence http-based proxy redirection?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

for the impatient just do the following; assuming that the proxy is `example.com:7777` and it's socks5 (change it with your own later)

- first install redsocks `sudo apt-get install redsocks`

, make an empty file anywhere and name it redsocks.conf (or whatever), I'll assume it's here `/etc/redsocks.conf` (change it with your own).

- edit the file you created (redsocks.conf) as follows

> ```
> base {
>  log_debug = on;
>  log_info = on;
>  log = "stderr";
>  daemon = off;
>  redirector = iptables;
> }
>
> redsocks {
>     local_ip = 127.0.0.1;
>     local_port = 12345;
>
>     ip = example.com;
>     port = 7777;
>     type = socks5;
>       // known types: socks4, socks5, http-connect, http-relay
>
>     // login = username;
>     // password = password;
>         }
> ```

change `example.com` `7777` with your proxy,
(note that you can use any `local_port` other than `12345`,it's the local port that we will set an iptable rule to redirect the traffic to, so if you use another, make sure to use it in later steps below)

-- now run redsocks with the config file destination as follows

```
sudo redsocks -c /etc/redsocks.conf
```

change with the destination of your redsocks.conf
(if you get "bind: Address already in use" try `killall redsocks`)
you can also check if redsocks is bound to local port 12345 with `netstat -tulpn`

-- now that redsocks is running and ready, let's change the iptables rules to use redsocks. this should be customized to your needs, but if you like to redirect all HTTP and HTTPS packets through the proxy. Define the following rules.

```
sudo iptables -t nat -N REDSOCKS

sudo iptables -t nat -A REDSOCKS -d 0.0.0.0/8 -j RETURN
sudo iptables -t nat -A REDSOCKS -d 10.0.0.0/8 -j RETURN
sudo iptables -t nat -A REDSOCKS -d 127.0.0.0/8 -j RETURN
sudo iptables -t nat -A REDSOCKS -d 169.254.0.0/16 -j RETURN
sudo iptables -t nat -A REDSOCKS -d 172.16.0.0/12 -j RETURN
sudo iptables -t nat -A REDSOCKS -d 192.168.0.0/16 -j RETURN
sudo iptables -t nat -A REDSOCKS -d 224.0.0.0/4 -j RETURN
sudo iptables -t nat -A REDSOCKS -d 240.0.0.0/4 -j RETURN
    
sudo iptables -t nat -A REDSOCKS -p tcp -j REDIRECT --to-ports 12345
    
sudo iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 443 -j REDSOCKS
sudo iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDSOCKS
    
sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 443 -j REDSOCKS
sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDSOCKS
```

now your http and https traffic should be redirected through `example.com:7777`

if you want your iptables reset use:

```
iptables -F
iptables -t nat -F
iptables -t mangle -F
iptables -X
```

Comment: After I run the two PREROUTING chains, I have no Internet connectivity. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You need to forward all outgoing local traffic using `iptables`.  Not aware of any GUI programs that do it.  My use of `iptables` is limited to either very simple written scripts to call it to build a router, etc or to do a typical host based firewall setup with `ufw`.  There is a GUI for `ufw` (`gufw`, imagine that) but I've never used it.

This (closed for being off topic) question/answer should get you started.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23180696/linux-iptables-redirect-outgoing-traffic-to-local-port

Comment: Redirecting traffic to a local port will not make that traffic SOCKS.

Answer (score 0):

I used your config file, but I faced a problem. And by referring to the [reference site](https://github.com/darkk/redsocks) and using the [main config file](https://github.com/darkk/redsocks/blob/master/redsocks.conf.example), I was able to complete the work.

Since I use v2ray on the system, instead of using the IP and port of the server, I used the IP and output port of v2ray.

This is my sample config code. If you want to use my code, delete the comments.

```
base {
log_debug = off;
log_info = on;
log = stderr;
daemon = off;
redirector = iptables;
}

redsocks {
local_ip = 127.0.0.1;
local_port = 1082; // I changed port number "12345" to this.
ip = 127.0.0.1; //goes from v2ray
port = 1081; //goes from v2ray
type = socks5;
}

redudp {
local_ip = 127.0.0.1;
local_port = 1083;
ip = 127.0.0.1; //goes from v2ray
port = 1081; //goes from v2ray
dest_ip = 8.8.8.8;
dest_port = 53;
udp_timeout = 30;
udp_timeout_stream = 180;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [mitmproxy](https://docs.mitmproxy.org/stable/overview-installation/) to intercept the traffic.

**All changes done with `sysctl` and `iptables` are reset on reboot.** If you want to persist this across reboots, you need to adjust your /etc/sysctl.conf or a newly created /etc/sysctl.d/mitmproxy.conf (see here).

### Work-around to redirect traffic originating from the machine itself (Linux)

From [mitmproxy docs](https://docs.mitmproxy.org/stable/howto-transparent/#work-around-to-redirect-traffic-originating-from-the-machine-itself).

#### Enable IP forwarding.

```
sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
sysctl -w net.ipv6.conf.all.forwarding=1
```

#### Disable ICMP redirects.

If your test device is on the same physical network, your machine shouldn’t inform the device that there’s a shorter route available by skipping the proxy.

```
sysctl -w net.ipv4.conf.all.send_redirects=0
```

#### Create a user to run the mitmproxy

```
sudo useradd --create-home mitmproxyuser
sudo -u mitmproxyuser -H bash -c 'cd ~ && pip install --user mitmproxy'
```

#### Configure the iptables rules.

Then, configure iptables to redirect all traffic from our local machine to mitmproxy. If you run into issues, `iptables -t nat -F` is a heavy handed way to flush (clear) all the rules from the iptables `nat` table (which includes any other rules you had configured).

```
sudo iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -p tcp -m owner ! --uid-owner mitmproxyuser --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8080
sudo iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -p tcp -m owner ! --uid-owner mitmproxyuser --dport 443 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8080
sudo ip6tables -t nat -A OUTPUT -p tcp -m owner ! --uid-owner mitmproxyuser --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8080
sudo ip6tables -t nat -A OUTPUT -p tcp -m owner ! --uid-owner mitmproxyuser --dport 443 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8080
```

This will redirect the packets from all users other than `mitmproxyuser` on the machine to mitmproxy. To avoid circularity, run mitmproxy as the user `mitmproxyuser`.

#### Run mitmproxy

```
sudo -u mitmproxyuser -H bash -c '$HOME/.local/bin/mitmproxy --mode transparent --showhost --set block_global=false'
```